# Firebase Auth is not working as expected. User is getting either logged in to the main screen or to the sign up page

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uikit, mac-catalyst

I am trying to work on the Firebase auth but it isn't able to successfully authenticate. I have an auth flow for the user to follow. But as soon as the user registers, they get shown the main screen rather than going to the other pages after the sign up flow. This piece of code is in my Scene Delegate in the `willConnectTo session` function.

```
weak var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] (auth, user) in
           if((user) != nil){
               let home = MainVC() 
            
            print("User is already signed in")
            
            self!.window?.rootViewController = home
            
           } else if((user) == nil) {
               print("Not Logged in")
               let signup = SignUpVC()
            self!.window?.rootViewController = signup
            
           }
       }
```

I will greatly appreciate if anyone can help out in solving this by any chance or give any possible hints.

Comment: Did you manage to try out my answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, in your SignUpVC you call `Auth.auth().createUser(..)`, before the user should continue to another signUp screen to complete his profile?

The problem is, after calling `createUser()` Firebase will call your `addStateDidChangeListener` again, with the newly created user object.
This time your check `user != nil` succeeds and your code will push the mainVC as rootVC.

---

So maybe you should check, if the user object is completely set up, too. If there are some settings missing, lead the user to CompleteSignUpVC.
Your code could look like this:

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] (auth, user) in
       if((user) == nil){
           print("Not Logged in")
           let signup = SignUpVC()
           self!.window?.rootViewController = signup
           return
       }
        
       if (user.isSignUpCompleted()) {
           print("User is already signed in")
           let home = MainVC() 
           self!.window?.rootViewController = home
       } else {
           print("User needs to complete signUp flow")
           let home = CompleteSignUpVC() 
           self!.window?.rootViewController = home
           
           // or otherwise, ignore this case and do nothing further, 
           // since your current flow will do the rest
       }
   }
```

---

If this may not solve your problem, then please provide more information about your apps signUp flow.